# Computing $\text{Res}_{z=\infty} \frac{e^{1/z}z^n}{z+1}$,

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer and define $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^{1/z}z^n}{z+1}$. I need to compute $\text{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z)$. I did the following:
$$\text{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z) = - \frac{1}{z^2} \text{Res}_{z=0}f(1/z) = - \text{Res}_{z=0}  \frac{e^z}{z^{n+1}(z+1)}.$$
Now, $\displaystyle \frac{e^z}{z^{n+1}(z+1)}$, has a pole of order $n+1$ at $0$, so
$$\text{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z) = -\frac{1}{n!} \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d^n}{dz^n} \left( \frac{e^z}{z+1} \right).$$
This last derivative is giving me a headache, I'd like to know if there's an easy way to compute it, or a complete different way to compute the residue which is easier (I tried with the integral definition of the coefficent $a_{-1}$ of the Laurent series and I arrived to the same derivative).

Comment: Consider series $\frac{1}{1+z}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-z)^n$ when $|z|<1$.

Comment: @twink (+1) And please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @metamorphy I tried to do that but I got the same derivative using the Cauchy's differentiation formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on application of [Leibniz's Product Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule).  To that end we proceed.

Applying Leibniz's Rule to the function $\frac{e^z}{z+1}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(\frac{e^z}{z+1}\right)&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\underbrace{\frac{d^{n-k}e^z}{dz^{n-k}}}_{e^z}\,\,\underbrace{\frac{d^k(z+1)^{-1}}{dz^k}}_{(-1)^kk!(z+1)^{-(k+1)}}\\\\
&=e^z\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(z+1)^{k+1}}
\end{align}$$

Multiplying by $-\frac1{n!}$ and letting $z\to 0$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}(f(z), z=0)&=-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n}{(n-k)!}\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{k\mapsto n-k}-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k!}
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Beautiful. I didn't know the general Leibniz's Rule.

Comment: @Twink Pleased to see that this was useful!

Answer (score 4):

The residue of $\frac{e^z}{z^{n+1} (z+1)}$ at $0$ is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent series of that function about $0$, which is the coefficient of $z^{n}$ in the Maclaurin series of $e^z/(z+1)$.  Now $e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k/k!$ while $1/(z+1) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j z^j$, so that coefficient is
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k!}$$
That can be written using an incomplete Gamma function as
$$ {\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n}\Gamma \left( n+1,-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{
-1}}}{n!}}
$$

Comment: The coefficient of $z^n$ in the Maclaurin series of $\frac{e^z}{z+1}$ is $\frac{1}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dz^n} \left( \frac{e^z}{z+1} \right)$, but I got a negative sign in what I did, that's strange... or maybe the limit changes the sign.

Comment: Can I use the Cauchy product rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Products_of_finitely_many_infinite_series instaed of the Gamma function? (I haven't seen that topic yet).

Comment: Yes, because you wanted $-$ the residue at $0$.

Comment: Ooh I see, at the end I have to change the sign.

Comment: P.S. I got the same result using the Cauchy product... thanks :D